# Redis master runs several more commands than the Redis slave

Tags: redis, master-slave

We are obtaining a very *interesting graph* in our Redis architecture.

[image: redis commands]

- Green: master
- Blue: slave

Looks like the *master Redis* is executing **35% more commands** than the *slave Redis*.

It is not always the same distance.

Here is part of the log of the active redis server:

```
[26911] 14 Feb 13:28:44 - DB 0: 2399 keys (417 volatile) in 16384 slots HT.
[26911] 14 Feb 13:28:44 - DB 1: 498 keys (498 volatile) in 1024 slots HT.
[26911] 14 Feb 13:28:44 - DB 2: 1 keys (0 volatile) in 4 slots HT.
[26911] 14 Feb 13:28:44 - 706 clients connected (1 slaves), 33794240 bytes in use
```

and during the same time on the salve:

```
[17748] 14 Feb 13:28:44 - DB 0: 2398 keys (417 volatile) in 16384 slots HT.
[17748] 14 Feb 13:28:44 - DB 1: 497 keys (497 volatile) in 1024 slots HT.
[17748] 14 Feb 13:28:44 - DB 2: 1 keys (0 volatile) in 4 slots HT.
[17748] 14 Feb 13:28:44 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 24839792 bytes in use
```

So they look like they are almost 1:1 synchronized.

We wonder which can be the cause of this gap. Also we are asking our selves if this means there are unnecessary commands sent to Redis that we can optimize.

Comment: Any read commands would not be propagated to the slave, I guess. Are you only writing to the master, and reading from the slave? If you are reading from/writing to the master, and not reading from the slave, that would explain it.

Comment: ouch!.. good point.. you can add your comment as an answer so people (and me) can turn it like the correct one.

Comment: I have added it as an answer for future reference. Please accept it if it was to your satisfaction! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible explanation: `total_commands_processed` reports all commands, reads, writes and server related commands. Only write commands will be propagated to the slave(s).

In a setup where you only write to the master, and read from the slave(s), you will have a higher `total_commands_processed` on the slave(s) (all reads + all writes).

If you write to and read from the master, and only keep the slave as a backup, or to persist to disk, the master will have a higher `total_commands_processed`.

In fact, it's very improbable that the master and slave will have the same number of `total_commands_processed`.

Comment: You have a point here!, we _write/read_ always _to/from_ the `master` server. If nobody say something else I'll check this one.

Comment: In that case, you would indeed have more `total_commands_processed` on the `master`, since `(writes + reads) > writes`.